# How can I provide billing details for SCA compliance using Stripe Payment Intents?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, strong-customer-authentication

I am using Stripe Payment Intents, following the instructions in the [Payment Intents Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#elements). As the docs note:

> To ensure that your integration is SCA-ready, be sure to always provide the customer’s name, email, billing address, and shipping address (if available) to the `stripe.handleCardPayment` call.

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_lolnothisisnotreal', {
  betas: ['payment_intent_beta_3']
})
```

Per [the handleCardPayment doc in the link](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-handle-card-payment), I am providing [billing details in the format specified](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-handle-card-payment):

```
// https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-handle-card-payment
const {paymentIntent, error} = await stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret, cardElement, {
  // https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-billing_details
  payment_method_data: {
    billing_details: {
      address: {
        line1: cardholderAddressLine1.value,
        line2: cardholderAddressLine2.value,
        city: cardholderAddressCity.value,
        state: cardholderAddressState.value,
        country: cardholderAddressCountry.value,
        postal_code: cardholderAddressPostalCode
      },
      name: cardholderName.value,
      email: cardholderEmail.value,
      phone: cardholderPhone.value
    }
  }
})
```

However `handleCardPayment()` returns:

```
Received unknown parameter: source_data[billing_details]
```

**How can I provide billing details for SCA compliance using Stripe Payment Intents?**

Answer (score 2):

The code is passing `payment_method_data[billing_details]` which is how you provide details such as the cardholder's billing address to associate it with the `PaymentMethod` resource that is created.

The issue though is that this only works if you have not initialized Stripe.js with an old beta flag where `handleCardPayment` would create a `Source` object (src_123) behind the scenes instead of a `PaymentMethod` (pm_123).

When you do that, the library will translate `payment_method_data` to `source_data` and then cause `source_data[billing_details]` to be sent, but the API server-side rejects it since it's not a valid parameter server-side.

To avoid this error, you need to ensure that you initialize Stripe.js without the `betas` flag. So turn

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_123', {   betas: ['payment_intent_beta_3'] });
```

into:

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_123');
```